# Apps not running in ios6 simulator

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using ios6 simulator. Do I require a separate simulator to run ios5 based applications?.

When I try to run a SampleApp. named **Twitterrush**.
There is error, a pop up arises which say

> The run destination iPhone 6.0 Simulator is not valid for Running the scheme 'TwitterRush

The scheme 'TwitterRush' contains no buildables that can be built for the SDKs supported by the run destination iPhone 6.0 Simulator. Make sure your targets all specify SDKs that are supported by this version of Xcode.

Comment: i guess no,you can run it

Comment: You can run the same app on ios 6 (IPhone 4 inch) simulator. if you want to switch the simulators you can change ir by Hardware>Device and select the desire simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your simulator option goto Hardware->Version->5.1

if 5.1 is not present there, goto Xcode->Preferences->Downloads->iOS 5.1 Simulator->Install

Hope this info helps you..

Comment: The run destination iPhone 6.0 Simulator is not valid for Running the scheme 'TwitterRush'.

Comment: what are your options set to for in the proejct options? you need to tell it is uses iOS6 as the deployment target or base sdk

Answer (score 0):

In your project settings->Info tab, what value do you see in iOS Deployment Target?
If it is 6.0, you will be unable to run it anywhere under simulator 6.0.
If it is 5.0, all versions of simulator => 5.0 will be able to run.

From XCode, you can select simulator version to run from 'Set Active Scheme' button, usually at the top left of your XCode project area.

Comment: Set Active Scheme' button, shows only ios 6.0 simulator..I have installed ios 5 simulator from  Xcode->Preferences->Downloads->iOS 5.1 Simulator->Install

Comment: Read my first paragraph above-that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, On your simulator option goto `Hardware->Version->5.1`

if 5.1 is not present there, goto `Xcode->Preferences->Downloads->iOS 5.1 Simulator->Install`